# Is it possible to create a very big bitmap over the size of 2^32?

Tags: c++, bitmap, mfc

I'm a junior in image processing.
Now, I'm trying to create a very big bitmap over the size of 2^32 in MFC Application.
because I need to add this function on the MFC Application I've been working for.
Is there anyway to create that size of bitmap? if possible, please leave a reply or clue on the comment!
Any reply or clue will be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: *Now, I'm trying to create a very big bitmap over the size of 2^32* -- You mean a Windows BMP image?  If so, you would be better off creating a TIFF that uses compression.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie thank you for your comment! I don't need to save it in bmp file. What I want is creating that size of bitmap and draw it on the dialog. Is there any method to do it?

Comment: First, what have you tried?  Whatever that is, where did it fail?  Is your program 32-bit or 64-bit?  If it's 32-bit, there is little chance whatever you want can be done, since 32-bit programs are limited in the amount of memory that it can use.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie ah I'm sorry for not describing well. My application is on 64 bit, and I used CreateDIBSection for creating bitmap, and it return NULL on a pointer to DIB bits, failed to create bitmap. I knew that It failed because of overflow. so I'm just trying to find another way to create that size of bitmap.

Comment: @Jay it's probably better to show the relevant parts of your code instead of describing them.

Comment: Do you really need a single 2gb bitmap? You're certainly never going to be able to draw that all on a dialog. Would you be better off just using an array?

Comment: You certainly cannot create a BMP file that's larger than `2^32 - 1` bytes due to the `bfSize` field in the [`BITMAPFILEHEADER`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/ns-wingdi-bitmapfileheader). Though most of the APIs for creating in-memory bitmaps allow you to omit the size, I doubt that the system is prepared to deal with bitmaps that are larger than could be stored. You'd have to have an **insanely** large display to actually show a bitmap that's larger than 4GiB. So then, what's the *real* problem you are trying to solve here?

Comment: @AlanBirtles Thank you for your comment! I understand that it cannot be possible to draw a bitmap over 2^32. so All I need to do is to find a way just to create that size of bitmap.

Comment: @IInspectable Thank you for your comment! yeah, you are right. I understand that It is impossible to draw a bitmap over 2^32. so What I want to solve is just to create that size of bitmap. any idea or clue will be appreciated!

Comment: A way to solve this is to create a bitmap of the actual physical size for display, and populate it from the raw data using some sort of filtering (e.g. point-sampling, bi-liniear filtering, etc.).